# python list problem-Why does the function produce light blue?-vscode

Tags: python, list, tuples

First Case

```
lst = [20, 5, 31, 94, 61, 39]

even_list = []
odd_list = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] % 2 == 0:
        even_list.append(lst[i])
        even_list.sort()
    elif lst[i] % 2 != 0:
        odd_list.append(lst[i])
        odd_list.sort()
    even_cnt = len(even_list)
    odd_cnt = len(odd_list)

print(even_cnt,odd_cnt,even_list,odd_list)
```

First case is working, so i made a function to sort even,odd (Problem Happen!!)

```
def list_even_odd(original_list):
    even_list = []
    odd_list = []
    for i in range(len(original_list)):
        if original_list[i] % 2 == 0:
            even_list.append(original_list[i])
            even_list.sort()
            even_count = len(even_list)
            
        elif original_list[i] % 2 != 0:
            odd_list.append(original_list[i])
            odd_list.sort()
            odd_count = len(odd_list)
    
list = [20, 5, 31, 94, 61, 39]
even_count, odd_count, even_list, odd_list = list_even_odd(list)
print(even_count, odd_count, even_list, odd_list)
```

In Vscode, it says that even_count,odd_count have a problem. How can i fix it?

Comment: You only set `even_count` and `odd_count` if that type of number is actually found; if there are no even numbers (for example), then `even_count` isn't zero, it's completely undefined.  And those are local variables in your function, anyway - you don't return them, so there's no way to use them in your top-level code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return` on your function. Try :

```
def list_even_odd(original_list):
    even_list = []
    odd_list = []
    for i in range(len(original_list)):
        if original_list[i] % 2 == 0:
            even_list.append(original_list[i])
            even_list.sort()
            even_count = len(even_list)
            
        elif original_list[i] % 2 != 0:
            odd_list.append(original_list[i])
            odd_list.sort()
            odd_count = len(odd_list)
    return even_count, odd_count, even_list, odd_list
```

Comment: Really Thanks. You saved me!!!